# Loop for Selenium and Python

Tags: python, loops, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, openpyxl

First I am super new at programming but have gotten my code to work so far, but want to figure out how to automate it, so I am not continually having to update my python code, and starting the program over and over.

The program scrapes 'planning authority data' over a year period with certain search parameters and then using openpyxl writes this into an excel file.

What I am trying to do is ---

1. Automatically search over a 10 year period (still have to do it on a year by year search)
2. Have each year on a different tab in excel.

If you have any assistance on either issue it would be appreciated. Tried to get rid of most of the junk code which wasn't necessary for the question.

Here is my code that I have for the program

```
python3 UrlScript.py    

Url to grab information off of
mainPage = "http://edevelopment.falkirk.gov.uk/online/search.do?action=advanced"

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl import load_workbook

description = ["window"]
ApplicationType = [0,11,12,31,32,33,46,47,61]
#DecisionType
startDate = "01/01/2012"
endDate = "31/12/2012"
error = False
year = 2012

#Excel
wb = load_workbook('/Users/Caitlyn/Desktop/Program/Planning.xlsx')
sheet = wb.get_sheet_by_name('Data')
rowIndex = 2
columnIndex = 1

driver = webdriver.Chrome('/Users/Caitlyn/Downloads/chromedriver')
driver.get(mainPage)

# placing each description here
sbox = driver.find_element_by_id("description")
sheet.cell(row=rowIndex, column=columnIndex, value=description[0])
columnIndex = columnIndex + 1
sbox.send_keys(description[0])

# here is where you will cycle through dates
sbox = driver.find_element_by_id("applicationDecisionStart")
sbox.send_keys(startDate)
sbox = driver.find_element_by_id("applicationDecisionEnd")
sbox.send_keys(endDate)
sheet.cell(row=rowIndex, column=columnIndex, value=year)
columnIndex = columnIndex + 1


    if error:
      resultsRow = rowIndex
      while True:
        column = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("searchresult")
        pageResults = pageResults + len(column)
        for element in column:
          list = element.text.split("\n")
          sheet.cell(row=rowIndex, column=columnIndex, value=list[0])
          columnIndex = columnIndex + 1
          sheet.cell(row=rowIndex, column=columnIndex, value=list[1])
          columnIndex = columnIndex + 1
          sheet.cell(row=rowIndex, column=columnIndex, value=list[2].split("|")[0])
          columnIndex = columnIndex - 2
          rowIndex = rowIndex + 1
        try:
          submit = driver.find_element_by_class_name("next")
          submit.click()
          pageIndex = pageIndex + 1
        except NoSuchElementException:
          break

      columnIndex = columnIndex - 1
      sheet.cell(row=resultsRow, column=columnIndex, value=pageResults)
      columnIndex = columnIndex - 1
    else:
      columnIndex = columnIndex - 1
      sheet.cell(row=rowIndex, column=columnIndex, value=0)
      columnIndex = columnIndex - 1
      rowIndex = rowIndex + 1

    driver.execute_script("window.history.go(-%d)" % pageIndex)
    error = False

  columnIndex = columnIndex - 1

wb.save('/Users/Caitlyn/Desktop/Program/Planning.xlsx')
```

Answer (score 0):

The first thing should do is break your code down into functions so that you can separate your openpyxl code from your Selenium code.

Regarding your openpyxl code: you should try and avoid using `ws.cell(…)` as much as possible: you can append a list of cells to an existing sheet using `ws.append(…)`. Where this isn't possible then use `enumerate()` to get reliable counters.

I would suggest further discussion should be moved to the openpyxl mailing list where it's easier to ask partial questions.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I am going to go through and work on updating everything now. Thanks as well for the openpyxl mailing list :)